# NFS volumes are not persistent in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I'm trying to mount mongo `/data` directory on to a NFS volume in my kubernetes master machine for persisting mongo data. I see the volume is mounted successfully but I can see only `configdb` and `db` dirs but not their subdirectories. And I see the data is not even persisting in the volume. when I `kubectl describe <my_pv>` it shows `NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)`

Why is that so?

I see in kubernetes docs stating that:

> An nfs volume allows an existing NFS (Network File System) share to be
>   mounted into your pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is
>   removed, the contents of an nfs volume are preserved and the volume is
>   merely unmounted. This means that an NFS volume can be pre-populated
>   with data, and that data can be “handed off” between pods. NFS can be
>   mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.

I'm using kubernetes version 1.8.3.

mongo-deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: mongo
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      name: mongo
      labels:
        name: mongo
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:3.4.9
          ports:
            - name: mongo
              containerPort: 27017
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongovol
              mountPath: "/data"
      volumes:
      - name: mongovol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pvc
```

mongo-pv.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv
  labels:
    type: NFS
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: "/mongodata"
    server: 172.20.33.81
```

mongo-pvc.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
  storageClassName: slow
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: NFS
```

The way I mounted my nfs share on my kubernetes master machine:

```
1) apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
2) mkdir /mongodata
3) chown nobody:nogroup -R /mongodata
4) vi /etc/exports
5) added the line "/mongodata *(rw,sync,all_squash,no_subtree_check)"
6) exportfs -ra
7) service nfs-kernel-server restart
8) showmount -e ----> shows the share
```

I logged into the bash of my pod and I see the directory is mounted correctly but data is not persisting in my nfs server (kubernetes master machine).

Please help me see what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that pods don't have permission to create files and directories. You can `exec` to your pod and try to `touch` a file in NFS share if you get permission error you can ease up permission on file system and `exports` file to allow write access.

It's possible to specify `GID` in PV object to avoid permission denied issues.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#access-control

Answer (score 0):

I see you did a `chown nobody:nogroup -R /mongodata`.
Make sure that the application on your pod runs as `nobody:nogroup`

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter `mountOptions: "vers=4.1"` to your StorageClass config, this should fix your issue.

See this Github comment for more info:

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/223#issuecomment-344972640